# C++ SDL segmentation fault

Tags: c++, debugging, opengl, segmentation-fault, sdl

I had my game working and then decided to try and implement a menu using the following [tutorial](http://youtu.be/k-m0q_uVnno).

I did not use the tutorial to create the game that was in prior tutorials that he created.

Whenever I compile and run the program it loads briefly, then closes and says `Process terminated with status 3 (0 minutes, 1 seconds)` in the build log of `code::blocks`.

UPDATE: I have updated the code for the pastebin link to what I have now, the error I am now getting from the debugger is

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
In TTF_SizeUNICODE () (E:\game\pong\bin\Debug\SDL_ttf.dll)
At E:\game\pong\main.cpp:27
```

UPDATE 2: Seems that I embarrasingly didn't have the font installed. I've installed the font & now the debugger gets to a point where the screen displays with the font of "Start" and "Exit", however, immediately after doing this the program freezes, no error's what so ever in the debuggger, and if I run the program normally, it just stops responding after the text is displayed, strange. Just realised after forcefully closing the window after launching the program from `code::blocks`, it returns this: `Process terminated with status -805306369 (0 minutes, 13 seconds)`.

UPDATE 3: Solved.

Comment: Please narrow down your problem yourself, using a debugger if necessary, and post the _relevant_ code inline here if you're still stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not initializing `screen` (line 220) before you're passing it to `showMenu` (line 224). AFAIK `SDL_SetVideoMode` returns a surface you could use for your `screen`.

Comment: I'm afraid i don't fully understand, i have moved 
"SDL_Surface* screen;
TTF_Font* font;"

to before the showMenu, but as for the SetVideoMode, should i copy my existing "SDL_SetVideoMode(600,400,32, SDL_OPENGL );" from line 172 to somewhere earlier such as line 12 (before showMenu)? You're reply is appreciated very much! Thank you for helping! :)

Comment: I said initialize not declare. Line 168 should be `screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(600,400,32, SDL_OPENGL );`

Comment: I have changed line 168, but the error still persists. I have updated the pastebin link to the current coding if you'd like to check :) The debugger still throws the same fault at the same line.

"Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
At E:\game\pong\main.cpp:31"

Thank you for the help, i'm very new to c++ and as you may tell, i'm not that good at it yet, but hoping to get better!

Comment: I have updated the code for the pastebin link to what i have now, the error i am now getting from the debugger is

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. In TTF_SizeUNICODE () (E:\game\pong\bin\Debug\SDL_ttf.dll) At E:\game\pong\main.cpp:27

As usual, any replies appreciated, thank you.

Comment: @JohnSmith It might be that you'll need to install the font first.

Comment: Wow. Well that's embarrassing! I've installed the font & now the debugger gets to a point where the screen displays with the font of "Start" and "Exit", however, immediately after doing this the program freezes, no error's what so ever in the debuggger, and if i run the program normally, it just stops responding after the text is displayed, strange.


EDIT: Just realised after forcefully closing the window after launching the program from code::blocks, it returns this:

Process terminated with status -805306369 (0 minutes, 13 seconds)